# Is there a math symbol for $f(x) > g(x)$ except when $x=0$, in which case $f(x)=g(x)$?

Tags: logic, notation

Title says it all, except that $x \in R^n$.     For want of a better choice, I've specified the amsmath symbol $\gtrdot$ for this relation, but probably this actually means something quite different that google hasn't revealed??    If no such symbol exists, and my choice means something different, does anybody have an alternative suggestion?      Thanks very much!

Comment: Use $\ge$ even thought it is equal in only a very specific circumstance.  You can detail that circumstance if it is relevant.

Comment: It sounds like you are saying that $f-g$ is positive definite. That is sometimes written "$f-g\succ 0$".

Comment: @MPW Thanks!   Looks like I indeed want positive definiteness.    I thought only matrices could have this property, but I guess not.     Wikipedia's definition requires differentiability for some reason, and also provides a local definition, so I guess I should specify *globally* positive definite?   In any event, I'll use $\succ$

Comment: This is a comment to the first answer provided below.   The problem is that I have a a proof involving a whole string of inequalities where I derive the property in question (i..e, f(x)-g(x)=0 except when x=0 in which case f(x) = g(x)) from previous instances where this property holds.     Initially I wrote out exactly this each time, but by the eighth time decided it was taking up *way* too much space, hence the search for an symbol.   I  like @MPW's suggestion, for this reason.

Comment: You can attach comments to answers. I stand by my advice, though. I still think what you need is terminology. You define the terminology the first time, then the second time you write "$\alpha(x)$ is [terminology] to $\beta(x)$" or whatever. Makes the paper smoother to read.

Answer (score 4):

No, there isn't, there doesn't need to be.

When you write "$f(x) > g(x)$, except when $x = 0$, in which case $f(x) = g(x)$," that's plenty clear. Getting carried away with symbols might obscure rather than clarify your meaning in this instance.

If you're dealing with a whole bunch of functions related to each other in this manner, what you might need is some kind of terminology. I don't know what that terminology is, so I'll just "marklarable" for the sake of providing examples. Thus, in your paper, you might write "$f(x)$ is marklarable to $g(x)$, as is $\alpha(x)$ to $\beta(x)$."

Answer (score 3):

You could define a Boolean function: $$D^+(f, g) = \delta^{f(0)}_{g(0)} | f(x) > g(x) \forall x \neq 0 |$$ Presumably everyone reading your paper knows what the Kronecker delta and the Iverson bracket are. It's much easier to look for a prior definition of a function than it is to look for a prior use of a symbol, as you yourself have already experienced.

For example, if $f(x) = 3x^2$ and $g(x) = \frac{x^2}{3}$, then $D^+(f, g) = 1$. But with the prime counting function $\pi_1(x)$ and the semiprime counting function $\pi_2(x)$, we'd have $D^+(\pi_1, \pi_2) = 0$ because we also have $\pi_1 = \pi_2$ for $-2 < x < 2$.

Then, later on, to use Bob's example, you could write $D^+(\alpha, \beta) = 1$.